# Edit table with array of objects on double click in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, data-binding

I have array of objects like this:

```
$scope.rows = 
[{
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
}, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
}, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
}, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
}];
```

Table created using ng-repeat:

```
<div id="structure">
    <table border='1|1'>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in rows">
            <td>
                <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num1}}</span>
                <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" autofocus/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num2}}</span>
                <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" autofocus/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num3}}</span>
                <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" autofocus/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Edit functions:

```
$scope.editItem = function (item) {
    item.editing = true;
};

$scope.doneEditing = function (item) {
    item.editing = false;
};
```

The problem is all the keys names are same in each object, how to double click and update the table values?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use **[Angular's `ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)** directive with your `inputs`, so they update the respective `item`, so each `input` value is binded to its corresponding `item` number.

For example in the fisrt column you define it like this:

```
<input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num1" autofocus/>
```

This is how should be your HTML:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in rows">
      <td>
        <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num1}}</span>
        <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num1" autofocus/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num2}}</span>
        <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num2" autofocus/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num3}}</span>
        <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num3" autofocus/>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

**Demo:**

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.rows = [{
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }];

  $scope.editItem = function(item) {
    item.editing = true;
  };

  $scope.doneEditing = function(item) {
    item.editing = false;
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="structure">
      <table border='1|1'>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in rows">
          <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num1}}</span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num1" autofocus/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num2}}</span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num2" autofocus/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.num3}}</span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num3" autofocus/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

To fix the problem you stated in comments, this is an updated Demo snippet that takes into account affecting only, clicked column instead of the whole row.

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.editableColumn = 0;

  $scope.rows = [{
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }, {
    num1: 56,
    num2: 78,
    num3: 89
  }];

  $scope.editItem = function(item, col) {
    item.editing = true;
    $scope.editableColumn = col;
  };

  $scope.doneEditing = function(item) {
    item.editing = false;
    $scope.editableColumn = 0;
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="structure">
      <table border='1|1'>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in rows">
          <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item, 1)">{{item.num1}}</span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing && editableColumn == 1" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num1"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item, 2)">{{item.num2}}</span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing && editableColumn == 2" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num2"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item, 3)">{{item.num3}}</span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing && editableColumn == 3" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-model="item.num3"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just added an `editableColumn` variable in the scope that will be always updated with the number of the column to be edited.

Comment: With this three columns are going into edit mode. I want only on tag to be in edit mode...

Comment: @Satyadev I don't get it? which column? How it should be updated?

Comment: If you double click on any of the columns, all the three columns get input box

Comment: Ah, it's due to your implementation you are applying `item.editing` to the whole `item`, instead of the `nums`.